# Installing OpenCV on Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

Hi I want to build an application using Java and the OpenCV on Eclipse. I used this link (http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html) to help me install it. Everything seemed to go smoothly however, when I tried finding the external JAR on eclipse, I could not find openCV in order to extend it to my native library location. Any insight?

Comment: I have successfully installed it on my terminal. When I tried finding where my opencv was located terminal gave me this : -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include

Comment: Like I named OpenCV for defined user libraries but I cannot find the external JAR to link it...

Comment: You could just use maven and put the dependency in the pom file